# XSLT CHOOSE function - select value from specific element when element name appears more times in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <ns11_tl>
        <ns9_userLabel>192.168.188</ns9_userLabel>
        <ns11_aEndTpRef>
            <ns7_rdn>
                <ns7_type>MD</ns7_type>
                <ns7_value>Server</ns7_value>
            </ns7_rdn>
            <ns7_rdn>
                <ns7_type>ME</ns7_type>
                <ns7_value>192.168</ns7_value>
            </ns7_rdn>
            <ns7_rdn>
                <ns7_type>FTP</ns7_type>
                <ns7_value>1:2:3-4</ns7_value>
            </ns7_rdn>
        </ns11_aEndTpRef>
    </ns11_tl>
</data>
```

I want to put into the field **`STRING2`** value from **`ns7_value`** element but only if **`ns7_type`** has value **`ME`**.
I tried with this code but it did not work result is empty.
I tried for testing purposes to put into the **`DESC`** element value from any **`ns7_type`** (just for testing) and I can retrieve it but code always returns null for **`ns7_value`** element.

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <max:SyncDWDMLINK>
    <max:DWDMLINKSet>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data/ns11_tl" />
    </max:DWDMLINKSet>  
    </max:SyncDWDMLINK>
</xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="ns11_tl"> 
    <max:DWDM>
        <max:DESC><xsl:value-of select="ns11_aEndTpRef/ns7_rdn/ns7_type"/></max:DESC>
        <max:STRING2>
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(ns11_aEndTpRef/ns7_rdn/ns7_type,'ME')">
        <xsl:value-of select="ns11_aEndTpRef/ns7_rdn/ns7_value"/>
        </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        </max:STRING2>
    </max:DWDM>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: how many nodes of these "<max:DWDM>" are you expecting in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are multiple `ns7_type` elements in your XML. You current statement `ns11_aEndTpRef/ns7_rdn/ns7_type` is selecting all of them, but when this statement is used in a `contains` function, which expects a string as the first parameter, it will only select the first node in the set.

You don't actually need `xsl:choose` here. You can simplify the code by making use of a condition in the xpath, like so:

```
  <xsl:template match="ns11_tl"> 
    <max:DWDM>
        <max:DESC><xsl:value-of select="ns11_aEndTpRef/ns7_rdn/ns7_type"/></max:DESC>
        <max:STRING2>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns11_aEndTpRef/ns7_rdn[ns7_type='ME']/ns7_value"/>
        </max:STRING2>
    </max:DWDM>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you. I have one more exception which I must process so if you can help me with this since I think I will need choose at the end. Value can have value some sufix after its value for example it may be "192.168" but it may be also "192.168/direction=sink" so in this case I need all before "/" so again 192.168. So in this case I should use contains and substring-before functions. Can you please help me with this also? Sorry for additional disturbing. I marked your answer

Comment: Just do `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat(ns11_aEndTpRef/ns7_rdn[ns7_type='ME']/ns7_value, '/'), '/') "/>`

Comment: are you sure for this? Can you please test it?  it seems that  I am having some processing error: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR XP1037][ERR XPST0003] Parsing XPath expression 'substring-before(concat(ns11_aEndTpRef/ns7_rdn[ns7_t‌​ype='PTP']/ns7_value, '/'), '/') ' has caused an error.

Comment: Of course previous code was working but this new is not working. Probably there is some error... I cannot notice it

Comment: There seems to be an "invisible" character in the previous expression that has caused problems. See it working correctly at http://xsltransform.net/94AbWBs

Comment: thank you it's working now:) can you see where my error was? I can not notice that "invisible" character

Comment: You can see it if you paste the expression into xsltransform.net. See http://xsltransform.net/94AbWBs/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the same amount of "DWDM" nodes as "ns7_rdn" of your input, you should make the following changes to your xsl:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <max:SyncDWDMLINK>
        <max:DWDMLINKSet>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//ns7_rdn" />
        </max:DWDMLINKSet>
    </max:SyncDWDMLINK>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns7_rdn">
    <max:DWDM>
        <max:DESC><xsl:value-of select="ns7_type"/></max:DESC>
        <max:STRING2>
            <xsl:if test="contains(ns7_type,'ME')">
                <xsl:value-of select="ns7_value"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </max:STRING2>
    </max:DWDM>
</xsl:template>
```

This will produce this result which I suppose is what you expect

```
<max:SyncDWDMLINK>
<max:DWDMLINKSet>
<max:DWDM>
<max:DESC>MD</max:DESC>
<max:STRING2/>
</max:DWDM>
<max:DWDM>
<max:DESC>ME</max:DESC>
<max:STRING2>192.168</max:STRING2>
</max:DWDM>
<max:DWDM>
<max:DESC>FTP</max:DESC>
<max:STRING2/>
</max:DWDM>
</max:DWDMLINKSet>
</max:SyncDWDMLINK>
```

Please note the select in the "apply-templates" and besides it works with the "contains" function, you can just use `<xsl:if test="ns7_type='ME'">`

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi I cannot start with <xsl:apply-templates select="//ns7_rdn" /> because I need other nodes from the node which I have set. Can you please correct your answer?

Comment: you can fix it with a for each if you want to keep the original selection on the apply template,  ` <xsl:for-each select="//ns7_rdn">` in the "ns7_rdn" template

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="data" />
```

instead.

Comment: no it does not work...and as I mentioned everything else in the code works except this part only so I do not think it is related to apply template part